# HPC slurm - how to make an HPC node run multiple jobs' bash scripts at the same time

Tags: slurm

Let's suppose I have an HPC cluster with one node (`node_1`) and I want to send and run at the same time 3 jobs' bash scripts in `node_1`.

So far, when I send a job to `node_1` the node is kept busy until the job ends.

How can I do this?
Shall I provide any specific argument in the job's bash script?

thanks

---

Update

Here below an example of a bash script I am using to send a job to the HPC:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=my_job
#SBATCH --partition=test
#SBATCH --nodelist=node_1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=01:00:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=8000
#SBATCH --output=1.out
#SBATCH --error=1.err

python /my/HPC/folder/script.py
```

---

Update

```
(base) [id@login_node ~]$ scontrol show node=node_1
NodeName=node_1 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=32 
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=64 CPULoad=2.94
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=(null)
   NodeAddr=node_1 NodeHostName=node_1 Version=18.08
   OS=Linux 4.20.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Dec 23 20:11:51 EST 2018 
   RealMemory=128757 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=111815 Sockets=1 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=945178 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=test 
   BootTime=2019-12-09T14:09:25 SlurmdStartTime=2020-02-18T03:45:14
   CfgTRES=cpu=64,mem=128757M,billing=64
   AllocTRES=
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 LowestJoules=0 ConsumedJoules=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
```

Comment: How are you submitting your job? Also, the Slurm configuration may not allow sharing of nodes. If you are looking to over commitment resources you need to configure that as well.

Comment: thanks. I updated the question with a bash script's example.

Comment: I assume you are using sbatch to submit this. How is you node defined in your slurm.conf?

Comment: yes I use sbatch. I don’t know about the slurs.conf file..

Comment: Would you please run: scontrol show node=node_01

Comment: thanks. please see the output in the updated question..how can I configure node_1 so that its resources can be shared?

Comment: That helps. Try removing --cpus-per-task as a start. You can also try --overcommit .

Comment: nope. sorry. I tried both suggestions..also with different combinations. but a second job sent to the same node always goes to "Resources". note: I specify --overcommit in the bash script and then send the job with sbatch. I also do not use srun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the consumable resource type from **nodes** to **cores** in slurm.

Add this to your `slurm.conf` file

```
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
```

SelectType: Controls whether CPU resources are allocated to jobs and job steps in units of whole nodes or as consumable resources (sockets, cores or threads).

SelectTypeParameters: Defines the consumable resource type and controls other aspects of CPU resource allocation by the select plugin. 
[Reference](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cpu_management.html)

Also, the node description should also allows for that:

```
NodeName=<somename> NodeAddr=<someaddress> CPUs=16 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=4 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=12005 State=UNKNOWN
```

See also [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/855212/run-multiple-jobs-on-same-slurm-worker-in-parallel)

Comment: Thanks. How can I find the slurm.conf file?

Comment: It is normally in the location PREFIX/etc. PREFIX is where you have installed your slurm.